# what is the difference between Session and ModelAttribute in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
 @ModelAttribute and Session
```

when i was searching about model Attribute i found tutorials that store entire Object like user but i    can do it also with Session to identify the User

what i want to know is what is the difference between Session and ModelAttribute and when to use Session and when to Use ModelAttribute`